# Improper decoding of raw H264 video stream using android MediaCodec

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, android-mediacodec, screencast

I am building a screen sharing app and trying to receive raw H264 video stream from a socket and displaying it using surfaceview by decoding using MediaCodec class. However I am successfully able to receive data and display on surface. But the problem where I am stuck from two days is the video is very laggy,jittery and having green bands and patches. You can see the issue in the youtube [video link](https://youtu.be/2Bfd2HGFFn0). If I save this video to sdcard and play it using MxPlayer then it is playing fine.Also I tried with Gstreamer and everything is fine.
This is my class calling from Activity when surfaceview is created.

```
//New Edited Code
public class Server {
static final int socketServerPORT = 53515;
MainActivity activity;
ServerSocket serverSocket;

public Server(MainActivity activity, Surface surface) {
    Log.e("constructor()", "called");
    this.activity = activity;
    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread(surface));
    socketServerThread.start();
}

private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);

        if (codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                Log.e("codecinfo", codecInfo.getName());
                return codecInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    Socket socket;
    private MediaCodec codec;
    private Surface surface;

    public SocketServerThread(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("socketthread", "called");
        try {
            selectCodec("video/avc");
            codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(selectCodec("video/avc").getName());

            MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 800, 480);
            //  format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1024000);
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
            codec.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
            codec.start();
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.e("connection", "accepted");
                is = socket.getInputStream();
                if (is != null) {
                    //          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/stream.mp4");
                    //              OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    byte[] buff = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                    int read;
                    while ((read = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
                        //              output.write(buff, 0, read);
                        if (buff.length == 1)
                            continue;

                        int inIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                        if (inIndex >= 0) {
                            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                            inputBuffer.clear();
                            inputBuffer.put(buff);

                            codec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, buff.length, 16, 0);
                        }

                        MediaCodec.BufferInfo buffInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                        int outIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(buffInfo, 10000);

                        switch (outIndex) {
                            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                                break;
                            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                                break;
                            case -3:
                                break;
                            default:
                                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (codec != null) {
                codec.release();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the way you mentioned to create MediaCodec as

```
MediaCodec.createByCodecName(selectCodec("video/avc").getName());

   private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);

        if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                Log.e("codecinfo",codecInfo.getName());
                return codecInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but it gives me error

```
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] setting surface generation   to 28345345
W/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Failed to set standard   component role 'video_decoder.avc'.
E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -1010
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -1010)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xfffffc0e, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xfffffc0e, resetting...
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.androidsrc.server, PID: 27681
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffc0e
at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1884)
at com.androidsrc.server.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:70)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Also I tried to create Mediacodec earlier by this method

```
codec =  MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
```

but the video quality remains same as in the video shared on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment this but still missing the required points :D

I think you (or i'm not aware that it' works otherwise) are missing some important bits. The video you provided shows signs of missing information on how to interpret things.

- Are you sending and using SPS and PPS? I'm not sure if the MediaFormat you create contains all the needed information.
- MediaCodec requires entire frames to be fed to it. Are you sure that you receive a full frame using this sort of logic?
- Some Decoders expect the frames without a NAL header. Are you sending frames without NAL headers?
- I don't see you transfer any presentation time

I suggest you Look at RTP/RTSP protocol on how to transfer media.
To further help you i suggest you provide the producer logic as well

Comment: ChrisBe is right, TCP is not a good network layer to transfer live video. Also, what is the source of your h264 packets? Maybe they are not compatible with your client side.

Comment: Please have a look, I am using this [screenCast project on github](https://github.com/JonesChi/CastScreen). As it works good with gstreamer app on my ubuntu or from mxPlayer on my android if I save this stream to sdcard.

Comment: You really need to have another look at the sourcecode. The first thing that is sent is the HTTP_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE, with the video dimensions, filter that out. If AVC is selected, SPS and PPS are sent next. You need to feed that to the decoder using the BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG flag. I Also suggest that you use a different approach for transfering H264 avc frames than just plain tcp writes and reads. If you want to sick with this project use VP8 as the provided IvfWriter makes transfers frames in [ivf format](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/IVF)

Comment: I agree what you said. I am looking towards rtsp. I will research about how I can implement it and let you know. :)

Comment: @ChrisBe: ivf does support h264, too. This is what screencast uses.

Answer (score 0):

`OMX.google.h264.decoder` is a software codec with a limited functionality (at least on some devices and api levels).

Try to use `createDecoderByType` instead of `createDecoderByName` or to choose another codec as in the example here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html
(modify it to choose decoder other than `OMX.google.h264.decoder`)

Comment: you should remove the '!' in `!codecInfo.isEncoder()` in your code.

Please note that the youtube link in your post is "private".

Comment: My apologies. I have made the link public now you can see it. Also I made the changes as you said. I have edited question with new code.Please have a look and this is [new video](https://youtu.be/xHpR0-Q3kxY) according to new code changes. Decoding got more worse with hardware decoder which it returns itself. I my case it returns "OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc"

Comment: @neerajsinha the hw decoder is less forgiving than the sw. But anyways you need to parse ifv frames and feed the extracted buffers one by one to MediaCodec instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce timeout on dequeue (codec.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);), unless you think it does take so much time to decode.

Also setup following flags:

`mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);`

You mentioned that you changed code to select by type but original post had errors when decoder was created. Are you able to fix those errors?

You do need to use hardware decoder to ensure that you can play without significant performance cost. New video definitely is worst than first attempt, which means you had decoder selection issue. You can use ffplay with -f h264 option and confirm that format is correct.

Lastly, look into video dimensions and you can read back buffer from decoder (by passing false in releaseOutputBuffer) and write it to disk to confirm your dimensions are correct. Raw video to final video will have different dimension. Read width, height from codecFormat to confirm it is able to decode correctly.